# How to design button with gradient and shadow for Android?

Tags: android, xml, button, colors

How do I create buttons like the one below in Android? For the most part I have the main section of the button down. I can't seem to figure out the shadow and the clicking animation.

Button

```
<Button
    android:text="Connect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/connectionStatus"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    />
```

Here is the drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#21D4FD"
        android:endColor="#B721FF"
        android:angle="45"
    />
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="20dip"
        android:topRightRadius="20dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dip"
    />
</shape>
```

This is what I currently have:

[image: What I have]

This is what I want to have:

[image: What I want]

Comment: Look in to elevation for the shadow effect. As far as I am concerned for the buttons, you may want to use ImageButtons with gradients embedded from software such as Photoshop. 

https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [This](http://angrytools.com/android/button/) to make gradient on your button.

to know more please click [Here](https://materialdoc.com/components/buttons/)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that 4 Buttons in your image. I combined a library with my own `drawable` and a trick and reached a `Button` like you were searching for. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583069/how-to-put-shadow-with-gradient/68583416?noredirect=1#comment121206057_68583416) and here is my Spoiler:

[image: My approach]