# How to put shadow with gradient

Tags: java, android, drawable, android-button

How can i put gradient of two or three color in the shadow of Button?

I have only find the way to change the color of the shadow, but i need at least two colors in the shadow

You can find an example in the link below

[Button Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqrBZ.png)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Foreword:**

I saw that there were dozens of requests for this type of `Button`. And in fact, there has not yet been a real `Button` that has color `gradients` as areas and shadows. I found a [library](https://github.com/SMehranB/GlowNeonButton) that has `gradients` in the shadows. However, you cannot use a color `gradient` for the solids. Therefore I created a `drawable` myself (`custom_shape.xml`) which has it. Now we have separate shadows and areas. I combined the two and used a trick. The shadow of the library `Button` is covered by my `drawable`. But if you use a transparent `stroke` on my `drawable`, the shadow shines through.

**Execution:**

Install the package in your `build.gradle(Module:)`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

In your other folder called `build.gradle(Project:)` you need to implement the mentioned library:

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.github.SMehranB:GlowNeonButton:2.0.1'
}
```

Define your button as follows in your `activity_main.xml`:

```
<com.smb.glowbutton.NeonButton
    android:id="@+id/btnNeonOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:nb_cornerRadius="90dp"
    app:nb_gradientEnd="#FF6D00"
    app:nb_gradientStart="#AEEA00"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_shape"
    app:nb_text="Upvote"
    app:nb_textColor="#ffffff"
    app:nb_textSize="16sp"
    app:nb_textStyle="normal" />
```

After that you need to define my created `drawable`, set as `android:background="@drawable/custom_shape"` for the `Button`:

This is the custom drawable called `custom_shape.xml`:

Result:

[image: Gradient Button]

If you look closely, you can see that the shadow only has 2 `gradients`. Apple green on the left and orange on the right. However, the area of ​​the `Button` has 3 `gradients`. From the left apple green, light blue and orange.

**Closing Word:**

This combination is so far the only approach that has brought me to such a `Button`. The library's neon `Button` is not that modifiable, which led me to this combination. It was actually a happy coincidence / accident that gave me this idea.

Comment: I think shadow is missing :)

Comment: I'm glad you like the library. if you would like more modifiable attributes, feel free to request it on the github repository and I will try to add it in the next version.